# Inner join query running very slow with indexed table?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm running a two table inner join query on MySQL server and it is very slow, it takes 3 hours to finish.

```
UPDATE table_A ta
  JOIN table_B tb 
    ON ta.field1= tb.field1 
   AND ta.field2 = tb.field2
   SET ta.field2 = tb.field2, 
    ta.field3 = tb.field3
WHERE tb.field5 = 'ABC'
```

table_A has 650,000 rows
table_B has 100,000 rows

Both ta.`field1`, ta.`field2`, tb.`field1`, tb.`field2`, tb`field5` are all indexed and shown in the EXPLAIN results.

Any idea how to make it run faster?

Comment: add the index creation sql, maybe index is incorrect, obviously want an index on tb.field5

Comment: You are updating fields you have index on. Why do you even need it?

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but please in the future, when you ask for query optimization help, include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query so we can see the data types, indexes, and constraints. Also include the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
UPDATE `table_A` ta INNER JOIN
       table_B tb
       ON ta.`field1`= tb.`field1` AND ta.`field2` = tb.`field2`
SET ta.`field2` = tb.`field2`, 
    ta.`field3` = tb.`field3`
WHERE tb.`field5` = 'ABC';
```

There is no need to update `field2`, given that the new value is the same as the old value (based on the `join` condition).

One of these index approaches should work best:

- `table_B(field1, field2, field5)`
- `table_B(field5, field1, field2)`, `table_A(field1, field2)`

Which works better depends on the nature of the data.  It is very important, though, that you are using composite indexes, not separate indexes on each field.

Comment: Ok. will try both out and see.. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you updating field2? !?!

Comment: @Strawberry . . . That is a really good question.  Ask the OP.